Installing 'docker compose' plugin or standalone on 'Mac apple silicon' without 'docker desktop'
I am trying to install 'docker compose' plugin on 'Mac apple silicon' machine. My org doesn't allow 'Docker Desktop' so we use 'colima' instead. There is no official documentation to install the 'compose' plugin on mac without 'docker desktop'.
The links and instrutions for 'Compose Apple Binary' that that I have extracted on various blogs and 'chat gpt' are giving 404.
Please help in installing the 'docker compose' plugin or standalone on 'Mac apple silicon' without 'docker desktop'

Do the official Docker Install the plugin manually instructions work for you?  In particular, the GitHub Compose releases seem to include docker-compose-darwin-aarch64 binaries.

There are no instructions for installing the plug-in manually on Mac. Linux and Windows only.

Here's how you do it.
If you can use Homebrew, do
brew install docker-compose

and pay heed to the notes after the installer runs. They tell you to add
 "cliPluginsExtraDirs": [
     "/opt/homebrew/lib/docker/cli-plugins"
 ]

to your ~/.docker/config.json file.
I don't know if Homebrew also installs Credentials Helper with Compose, so you might have to do:
brew install docker-credential-helper

If you can't use Homebrew, I think you'll have to do the following.
Install Credentials Helper using Docker's instructions here.
Go into ~/.docker/config.json and make sure the value for credsStore is osxkeychain. My file looks like:
{
    "auths": {},
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain",
    "currentContext": "colima",
    "plugins": {
        "debug": {
            "hooks": "exec"
        },
        "scout": {
            "hooks": "pull,buildx build"
        }
    },
    "features": {
        "hooks": "true"
    }
}

Download latest Docker Compose from here for your architecture (aarch64 for Apple Silicon): https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest
Copy the executable to /usr/local/bin, naming it docker-compose.
From there, make sure it's executable:
sudo chmod +x docker-compose

Clear Apple's scareware:
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine docker-compose

As in the Homebrew case, add
 "cliPluginsExtraDirs": [
     "/opt/homebrew/lib/docker/cli-plugins"
 ]

to your ~/.docker/config.json file.
Open a new terminal session and try
docker compose version

If that doesn't work, try
docker-compose version

If that works, the cliPluginsExtraDirs entry in the config.json file isn't working.

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest this link doesn't have 'aarch64 for Apple Silicon;

@NeeteshKumarGupta It's the first one in the list! https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.29.3/docker-compose-darwin-aarch64

Worked fine. Thanks @Oscar!

@NeeteshKumarGupta Glad it worked for you! If you accept my post as the answer, more people might find it.
